# Spring security login - WebSecurityCongiurerAdapter

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, spring-security

I have my users stored in a database, the class for users looks like this

```kotlin
@Entity
data class User(
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        val id:Long = 0,
        val joinDate: LocalDateTime,
        val userName:String,
        val firstName:String,
        val email:String,
        val password:String,
        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinTable(name = "users_roles", joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")], inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id")])
        val roles:List<Role> = listOf(),
        @Column(name = "enabled")
        var enabled:Boolean = false
)
```

```kotlin
@Repository
interface UserRepository:JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    fun findByEmail(email:String):User?

    fun findByUserName(userName:String):User?
}
```

I have got the registration setup, however the login is the part I am struggling with. I have found several examples online, however they are all for hard-coded logins, and I cannot find any for databases , like I have. I have done this in past ( months ago - no longer have project), and I remember not doing it just with a PostMapping thing, but with these methods

```java
@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)

and

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http)
```

from WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.

If anyone knows where I can get started that would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your web adapter this way:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.denyAll();
    }
    
    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
    
    @Override
    @Autowired
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(this.userDetailsService);
    }

}
```

In user details service, you can verify the user details:

```
public class UserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

     // this should return spring security user details, and throw an error if not found
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, Ill have a look. From what I can see tho, HttpSecurity does not have a denyAll method? Also, in the loadUserByUsername method, how do I compare the users entered details to the login form with that one.

Comment: Yeah, you can use httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().denyAll(); For the latter part, which type of security are you using? Servlet, JWT.. etc?

Comment: ah, alright. Thanks for that first bit, now not entirely sure what you mean, im using spring security combined with thymeleaf

Comment: Have a look at the following link, you can ignore the role based security if you want  https://www.javaguides.net/2018/09/spring-boot-spring-mvc-role-based-spring-security-jpa-thymeleaf-mysql-tutorial.html